# why after returning from link_to :remote => true the entire form is submitted?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, link-to-remote

I have an action in a form that 
1) selects a product from a listbox
2) calls a remote controller action that returns how many items of that product are available in different warehouses

This is done using link_to with :remote => true

```
  <div id="products"></div>
  <%= link_to 'Search product', "#", class: 'get_product', :remote => true %>
```

Then there is a javascript

```
$('form').on('click', '.get_product', function(event) {
    var url;
    url='/recipes/get_product_list';
    url += '/' + $('#recipe_product_id').val();
    $.get(url, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return event.preventDefault();
});
```

I have the .js.erb templates and the correct values are returned in the .html.erb partial.

The problem is that after returning the partial, the page gets fully reloaded, and I do not want this.

Why is this happening?
I also tried to figure out how to invoke link_to with the entire url instead of using "#" and jquery, but in this case I do not know how to pass the value in the select field in the link_to helper.

Comment: Post the generated form html

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag, put this

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Without seeing your form HTML, it's hard to say why this is happening, but I think that the get_product button is submitting the form AND calling the on click handler function.

Comment: Yeah definitely without seeing the HTML it's tough to tell. get_product is a link though.